# make -v report really strange problem

Tags: apt, make

I'have some problem with build-essentials on Debian Stretch.
Since an npm command fail, and the symptom is build-essentials not installed, I reinstalled it from scratch. When checking version, all seems ok except make:

```
make -v
```

reports `/usr/bin/make syntax error near unexpected token`....

What can be wrong? it seems to run make as if it was a shell script ( just my guess ) how this can be?

**UPDATE** By reinstalling just make, it worked:

```
apt-get install make --reinstall
```

sooo reliable system...

[image]

Comment: Not reproducible... so not a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `/usr/bin/make` was at least partially overwritten with something else. This might mean you have some filesystem corruption. Which filesystem type(s) are you using?

You might want to run a full filesystem check to see if you have more filesystem corruption than just one overwritten `/usr/bin/make`. If you are using XFS, you should be aware that the generic `fsck` or `fsck.xfs` commands do *nothing at all* for XFS filesystems, as this filesystem type is supposed to do all "routine" checks internally. To just check for errors on a XFS filesystem, you should use `xfs_repair -n`. As always, filesystem checks should be run with the filesystem in question unmounted, or mounted as read-only if it's your root filesystem.